# discord.py receive empty strings instead of messages

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, message

I am making a discord bot on Python with discord.py

I've that problem, when I run the bot, it works, but it receives empty strings instead of messages.

test responses:

```py
import random


def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    if p_message == 'hello':
        return 'Hey there!'

    if p_message == 'roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))

    if p_message == '!help':
        return "`This is a help message that you can modify.`"

    #  return 'Yeah, I don\'t know. Try typing "!help".'
```

main:

```py
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

problematic code AKA bot:

```py
import discord
import responses


# Send messages
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'Our_Token'
    client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # Make sure bot doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        # Get data about the user
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        # Debug printing
        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")

        # If the user message contains a '?' in front of the text, it becomes a private message
        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]  # [1:] Removes the '?'
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    # Remember to run your bot with your personal TOKEN
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

After every message, the console returns:

[image: discord message console]

Expected behavior:

It should receive the message (not empty string) and if the message is in the responses.py, it should return a message (the bot should send message).

Comment: You're trying to convert the message. author and message. content to string, but these are already strings, you don't need to convert them again. Also, you don't need to use str() when you're trying to print them.

Comment: The author is **not** a string already, it's a `User/Member` instance. And putting `str()` around `message.content` might not be necessary, but it doesn't do anything so it's not the reason for OP's issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't enabled the `message_content` intent - you need to set that to be able to read message content.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # explicitly enable the message content intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

You will also need to enable this intent for your bot/application in the Discord Developer portal.

- The `message_content` intent is on the [first page of the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).
- [Discord intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).

Comment: Thank you, I don't have time right now though, but tomorrow I'll try it. Whatever happens, thanks for your support!

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked! Now I can                  finally add my changes and host the application :)