# I need my bot to delete links and videos sent by a certain discord user

Tags: discord.py

I have the link part down but it gives me a 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message error when i send a link the main problem is that if i try any other methods of writing this code for example i copied some code that deletes all of the messages sent in a chat but it still gives me the same error.

```
import discord
import responses

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = ''
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.messages = True
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)





    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.author.id == 0000000000000 and message.startswith("https"):
            await message.delete()
            # can return here as we deleted message - no need to process anything else
            return

        username = message.author.name
        user_message = message.content
        channel = message.channel.name
        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')
        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)


    client.run('')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py receive empty strings instead of messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127865/discord-py-receive-empty-strings-instead-of-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comments into an answer;

Firstly, you need to enable the `message_content` intent to be able to see message content. You will need to enable the `message_content` Privileged intent in the Discord developer portal as well.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Then, there should only be one `on_message` event. But we can merge them.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.id == 0000000000000 and message.startswith("https"):
        await message.delete()
        # can return here as we deleted message - no need to process anything else
        return

    username = message.author.name
    user_message = message.content
    channel = message.channel.name
    print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')
    if user_message[0] == '?':
        user_message = user_message[1:]
        await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
    else:
        await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)
```

I also changed the user ID to an int - as [`message.author.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.id) is an int. And changed stop of the `str()` calls to using the name properties as well.

Comment: Thank you very much but it throws a AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content' and i think my discord.py is up to date

Comment: What did your code end up looking like? It's [definitely an attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content).

Comment: I updated my code whit your's. Is the problem related to the position i put the code into?

Comment: Not sure; if it's just after you defined `intents` then should be fine. Did you enable the intent in the Discord Developer portal as well?

Comment: yes i enabled the server members message content and presence intents but still it doesnt work

Comment: Could you add your code somewhere? Just so I can have a look

Comment: Sure https://github.com/warlordgrog/discord-bot

Comment: That repo is private - you'll need to make it public for us to be able to see it :)

Comment: oh right now i thinks its public

Comment: Okay thanks. Doesn't look like you're doing that wrong. Are you definitely on version 2.0 and above for discord.py?

Comment: O yeah i installed pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py which is supposed to be discord.py 2.0 but now it gives me a  400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message error as a response to a gif sent in general chat

Comment: Your `send_messages` function in the github repo is trying to send an empty message. If the message starts with `?` and isn't one of the words in `responses.py`, it will still attempt to send `None` as the message.

Comment: oh so i need to put the code in the responses if i got that right?

Comment: or do i need to change the ? with something?

Comment: I'm actually confused with what the question/issue is now. Can you please clarify?

Comment: so i think the main problem is that i somehow need to put the code for deleting links in the responses file because it perfectly responds to simple if statements in the responses.py file but if the code is in the bot.py file under a @client.event it doesnt respond for some reason.

Comment: also these are the videos i copied my code from for the discord bot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yLfjMtsV9s&ab_channel=Indently https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoDLj0IzZMU&t=418s&ab_channel=Indently if that helps

Comment: I ended up creating a pull request on your repo for the changes to fix your empty message problem. We can move the discussion there as it's unrelated to this answer I think.