# message.content in discord.py has no information when message is sent

Tags: python, discord

I have a discord bot program that hasn't been modified since last year. While I have fixed the new indents requirement, whenever I send a message on a Discord server with full permissions to the bot, message.content has no data or strings I can use. This means that my program can not receive specific commands or messages.

Here is my code: Whenever I send a message to my discord server, it is supposed to print the message.author.mention and the contents of the message but it doesn't do this and only prints the author oddly.

This started happening when I reset my token because I mislocated it. Otherwise, it was working a few months before.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

print(message.author.mention + ' ' + message.content)

client.run('TOKEN HERE')
```

Comment: Do you also have the right intents set for your bot at https://discord.com/developers/applications/ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py receive empty strings instead of messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127865/discord-py-receive-empty-strings-instead-of-messages)

Comment: You probably don't have message contents enabled, you also need to explicitly state that you want that in the program and in the developer portal. `intents.messages = True`

Comment: @walker that's incorrect; `intents.messages` _doesn't_ give you message content. You need to `message_content` intent enabled.

Comment: I know that's why I said you needed to 'explicitly state that in the developer portal' as well. Please read my full comment more carefully.

Answer (score -1):

With the new Discord API updates, intents have been changed up a bit. To get the message content of a message, you need the `message_content` intent. This is a privileged intent. To enable this, enable it on the Discord Developer Portal, after that, you need to enable it in your code. Here's how you can do it:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

I hope this helps you out. If there any more problems/issues, feel free to comment.