# I have a python discord bot that is supossed to print out messages in a server + the author,instead of this it prints out blank characters

Tags: python, api, discord

My code,the error is most likely present in the def on_message line.
if there is any useful doccumentation that is related to this please link it down below

```
import discord

client = client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Bot is ready to read messages')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'{message.author}: {message.content}')


client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: does `message` actually contain `author` and `content` attributes? what gets returned if you try `print(vars(message))`?

Comment: ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\silky\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\silky\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 15, in on_message
    print(vars(message))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute @n1c9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py receive empty strings instead of messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127865/discord-py-receive-empty-strings-instead-of-messages)