# writing a script to make this bot come online in python, not sure why its not working, no error message

Tags: python, discord.py

my script looks like this:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!ping'):

        await message.channel.send('Pong!')

TOKEN = os.getenv('i would put le token here')
```

but i cant see an error message and it is not online. any tips/help please?

i fixed minor issues like intents and i think ive fixed the problem with the token expected to be a string, but when i run my code nothing happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py receive empty strings instead of messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127865/discord-py-receive-empty-strings-instead-of-messages)

Comment: Basically same answer as above; you're missing the right intents. Need to enable the `message_content` Intent in the code and enable it on the discord Developer Portal.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the bot for it to come online:

```
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Also, you don't put the actual token in the `os.getenv('le token')`, but in a .env file. Just to make sure you do it right:

**.ENV FILE**

```
DISCORD_TOKEN="token here"
```

**BOT CODE**

```
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
```

*Note: Make sure the .env file is in the same folder as your bot's code file (or specify the path for the .env file).*

Lastly, make sure you have the Message Content Intent enabled, both in the bot's code and on the bot's Application in Discord Developer Portal, so the bot can read messages.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default() #Making this a variable makes your life easier later on
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

The final (cleaned up) code should look like this:

```
import discord
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(command_prefix="insert prefix of choice", intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!ping'):

        await message.channel.send('Pong!')

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

***OPTIONAL STUFF***

If you want, instead of using an event to detect the command, use actual commands with a prefix.

```
client = discord.Client(command_prefix="[insert prefix of choice]", intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Pong!")
```

Comment: i tried this and got the error: TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__.__name__} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead

Comment: Your token is not formatted as a string. Make sure it looks like this:
`DISCORD_TOKEN="token here"`