# Why does message.content return empty unless my bot is pinged?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

For some reason, my bot can only read a message's content if it is pinged in the message. Otherwise, message.content is just an empty string.

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"1 - {message.content}")

  if client.user.mentioned_in(message) and client.user in message.mentions:
    print(f"2 - {message.content}")
```

Output:

```
1 - 
1 - <@1043377992409301074> hi
2 - <@1043377992409301074> hi
```

Messages:

[image: I sent the message "hi", then sent the message "hi" with a ping to my bot.]

Does anyone know how to make my bot able to read the message's content whether or not it is pinged in the message?

Comment: Is that `if` statement supposed to be inside the function definition?

Comment: Oh yeah it is, I forgot to indent it in this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py receive empty strings instead of messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127865/discord-py-receive-empty-strings-instead-of-messages)

Comment: If the intent was off, wouldn't the bot return an empty string for messages it was pinged in as well?

Comment: When the bot is mentioned in the message, it will be able to see its full content.

Comment: It works! But now whenever the bot receives a certain command, it shuts down and I have to manually turn it back on.